# Expo on iOS crashed without error

Tags: react-native, exponent

I am developing react native application via expo. Earlier everything worked well, but after I decided to translate my app into redux with one monster commit it began crash on iOS , but on Android well. What can be reason of such behavior? In debugger I put a lot of breakpoints, but I couldn't find where is that crashes. If I install osx on virtualbox with xcode and read logs will it help?

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was problem with `AsyncStorage`. I tried to save `null` into `AS`. On android it won't cause any error, but not on ios